# Using PHP in ColdFusion: how to convert or implement

Tags: php, coldfusion

I've been asked to build an "Are You Over 21?" popup on an distillery's website.  I normally code in PHP and the team was having a hard time getting me the login credentials for their site.  I figured while I waited I would code it up on my website and when they got me access I could just drop it over onto the new site (you can see what the popup looks like [on my site](http://trevorelwell.com)).  As luck would have it when they got me access to the site it was built using ColdFusion, which I have no idea how to use.  I've done some preliminary research on how to use CF but would prefer not to learn an entirely new language just for this one project.  I've included my code below, would someone be able to either 1) Show me how to implement PHP code in a CF landscape or 2) help me convert the code below into CF.  Thanks for your help!

### In the header:

This code is just looking to see if the 'over21' variable is set to 1 in the URL or if the previous session set the 'over21' variable.  If 'redirect' is set to 1 then it sends to google.com.

```
<?php if($_GET['redirect'] == 1){
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}?>

<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['over21']) || (isset($_GET['over21']))){
    if($_GET['over21']==1){
        $_SESSION['over21'] = 1;
    } elseif($_GET['over21']!=1){
        $_SESSION['over21']=0;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['over21']=0;
    }
} elseif($_GET['over21']){
    $_SESSION['over21'] = $_GET['over21'];
}
?>
```

### In the body:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['over21']) || ($_SESSION['over21']==0)){?>
    <div class="splash">
        <div class="splash-bg">
            <form method="get">
                <button class="yes-button" type="submit" name="over21" value="1" />
                <button class="no-button" type="submit" name="redirect" value="1" onclick="alert('Please come back and visit us when you are 21.')" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You can execute php from ColdFusion, but doing so would require far more effort and knowledge than implementing a few if/else blocks.  You really should rtfm, http://www.learncfinaweek.com might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not gonna write the code for you (where's the fun in that)? BUt here are some pieces of the puzzle:

- enclose a code block with `<cfscript></cfscript>` not `<?php ?>`
- instead of `$_GET`, params passed on the URL are referenced via the URL scope, eg: `URL.redirect`;
- no need to set HTTP headers to relocate to a different URL; use `location("http://google.com")`
- no need for associative array notation; just dot notation generally works (as per previous)
- instead of `isset()`, use `structKeyExists()`, eg: `structKeyExists(session, "over21")`
- `session` also is a scope, so just use dot-notation for its variables, eg: `session.over21`
- script syntax for the rest of the `if()` block is the same in CFML, including variable assignments and boolean operators.
- one cannot start a session like that; it needs to be configured @ application level (a concept I believe PHP still hasn't cottoned onto). Do you have an Application.cfc (or if old school: Application.cfm) in this directory on an ancestor directory? If so... erm... well read [the docs on Application.cfc](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Application.CFC+Reference). There's no point repeating them here.

As for the HTML bit, use CFML tags rather than script:

```
<cfif condition>
    <!-- mark-up here -->
</cfif>
```

The `condition` will me mostly as per above, except the operators are different. `EQ` for `==`, `OR` for `||`

It might be an idea to pop your code up on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion) afterwards so ppl can give it the once over.

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for pointing me in the right direction- I'll post what I come up with!